# Create groups for My sites in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to group wordpress My sites together. Right now I have a long list of sites and I need to group the similar ones. I have been trying to search for a plugin for this but haven't found any. Any hints or tips will be appreciated.

(example pic I found as an example)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did not try anything, i have just googled it.

Look at this link:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50235/how-to-add-custom-blog-options-to-new-blog-setup-form

Or this plugins:

https://github.com/brasofilo/multisite-site-category

https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/site-categories/